# Computer graphics: polygon mesh

Tags: graphics, polygon, normals

So a polygon mesh is defined as the following:

```
class Triangle{
int vertices[3]; //vertex indices
float nx, ny, nz; //face-plane normal
};
```

1. Is this a convenient way to represent a mesh used with flat shading? Explain
2. Suggest an object for which this is a good mesh format when used with Gouraud shading. Explain
3. Suggest an object for which this is a bad mesh format when used with Gouraud shading. Explain

So for 1, I said yes because the face plane normal can be easily converted to a point in the middle of the face. I read somewhere that normals don't have positions?

For 2 I said a ball; more gentle angles

And 3 a box; steeper angles.

I don't know, I don't think I really understand what the normal vector is.

Answer (score 0):

1. **mostly yes**

   from geometry computations is this OK however from rendering aspect having triangles in indices form only can be sometimes problematic (depends on the rendering engine, HW, etc). Usually is faster to have the triangle points directly in vector form instead of just indexes sometimes triangle contains both... However that is wasting space.
2. **depends on how you classify what is OK and what not.**

   smooth objects like sphere will look like this

   [image: sphere]

   while flat side meshes like cube will be rendered without visible distortions in shape (but with flat shaded like colors only so lighting will be corrupted)

   So answer to this is depend on what you want to achieve less lighting error, or better shape recognition or what. Basically using 1 normal for face will turn Gourard into flat shading.

   Lighting can be improved by dividing big flat surfaces into more triangles
3. **is unanswerable exactly for the same reasons as #2**

So if you want to answer **#2,#3** you need to clarify what it means good and bad ...